# I went on a walk in "the" forest in my backyard

Tags: definite-article

> In a moment of desperate need to feel God’s presence and listen to what He needed to tell me, I went on a walk in **the forest** in my backyard… [blog post](http://akgenasci.com/in-the-now/)

The above is first mentioned of the word "forest" within the article. but the writer used *the definite article*.

Do we use *the* with *forest*? or Does she use it because there is one forest on the area? or because the forest connected with her backyard?

Comment: There may be different forests in the area and so, to avoid confusion, the writer uses the definite article *the* to specify the particular forest where he went for a walk.

Comment: At least in American English, some article is needed before "forest" (British English sometimes leaves it out in cases where it is required in American English, like "I'm going to hospital"; Americans would say, "I'm going to school", though).  So it's a question of whether it should be "a" or "the".  "The" means there's just one forest in your backyard.  "A" means you have to choose which of the many forests in your backyard you will walk in, which wouldn't make sense unless your house was located at the convergence of a number of forests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article appears whenever the speaker has in mind a *specific* instance of the noun, as distinct from a generic instance (*any* or no particular one).

*Which* forest is the speaker talking about? *The* forest *in his back yard*.

This rule about the first mention has limited applicability. It is a pedagogical aid to help learners identify just one of the many situations where the definite article would be used.